# jquery toggle div one by one with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I want to toggle `showhide` div one by one when I click **link**. I have tried `find()` `next()` to target the div. But not able to achieve the desired result. Help me to achieve this.

For more clarification just drop your comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.showhide').hide();
  $('.divider a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(".showhide").slideToggle();
    $(this).parent().next().find(".showhide").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">
    <div class="divider">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
     <div class="divider">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="link-content">
    <div class="divider-desc">
        <div class="showhide">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
        <div class="showhide">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
        <div class="showhide">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean toggle say, the middle showhide if the link 2 is clicked, or show all showhide elements if any link is clicked, or?  (might update the question instead of another comment)

Comment: @PaulT. If I click link One first showhide will be visible as same like two and three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select by index. Use `.eq()` to select one by one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.showhide').hide();
      $('.divider').click(function(e) {  // note the change here
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".showhide").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle(); // and selector here with .eq
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">
    <div class="divider">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
     <div class="divider">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="link-content">
    <div class="divider-desc">
        <div class="showhide">
           1  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
        <div class="showhide">
           2  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
        <div class="showhide">
           3  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here its working. If I integrate into my wordpess website only first div target when click link 2, link3

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showhide').hide();
    $('.divider a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //$(".showhide").slideToggle();
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".showhide").slideToggle();
      console.log($(this).parent().parent().next().find(".showhide"))
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get index of the clicked element from `each` loop at once:

```js
$('.divider a').each(function(index){
  $(this).on('click', function(e){
    $('.showhide').eq( index ).toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); // just to indicate the opened links
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.showhide { display: none; margin: 5px; }
a.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divider"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024393/jquery-toggle-div-one-by-one-with-the-same-class#" target="_blank">Link 1</a></div>
<div class="divider"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
<div class="divider"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>

<div class="showhide">1111</div>
<div class="showhide">2222</div>
<div class="showhide">3333</div>
```